Vue Tailwind CSS Tabs component rendering wrong
I'm trying to use the Tailwind CSS tabs component to render content on my page like they show in their documentation, but the behavior I see when implementing does not match.
In my application, the tabs render as a row (like I want), but the content slots between each tab component, causing the tabs to break up when any but the last is selected. See the images below:
No tabs selected:

Last tab selected:

Middle tab selected ("Tab 3 remains in line with the other two tabs, but is off screen to the right [must scroll to see]):

My component code is below:
<script setup>
import { computed, inject, ref } from 'vue';

import AmortizationTable from './AmortizationTable.vue';
import constants from '../constants/constants';

const props = defineProps(['id', 'title', 'type']);
const emits = defineEmits(['exit-details-panel']);

const budgetPrimitives = inject('budgetPrimitives');
const builders = inject('builders');
const loanPrimitives = inject('loanPrimitives');
const visuals = inject('visuals');

const monthlyBudgets = ref(budgetPrimitives.monthlyBudgets);

const selectedTabIndex = ref(0);

const loan = computed(() => {
  const currentLoanId = loanPrimitives.currentLoanId?.value;
  return props.type === constants.LOAN && currentLoanId
    ? loanPrimitives.getLoan(currentLoanId)
    : loanPrimitives.getLoan(constants.TOTALS);
});

const paymentSummary = computed(() => {
  const currentLoanId = loanPrimitives.currentLoanId?.value;
  return props.type === constants.LOAN && currentLoanId
    ? visuals.paymentSummaries.value[currentLoanId]
    : visuals.paymentSummaries.value.totals;
});

const generateKey = (...args) => args.map((arg) => arg.id || arg).join('');

const emitExit = () => {
  emits('exit-details-panel');
};
</script>

<template>
  <base-modal :id="props.id">
    <template #header>
      <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    </template>
    <template #body>
      <div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-bordered w-full">
        <ul class="flex flex-row">
          <li v-for="budget in monthlyBudgets" :key="generateKey(loan, budget)">
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="amortization_tables"
              :id="'tab' + index"
              role="tab"
              class="tab"
              :aria-label="`Tab ${budgetPrimitives.getBudgetIndex(budget.id)}`"
            >
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content p-10">
              <AmortizationTable
                :id="'amortizationTable' + generateKey(loan, budget)"
                :keyPrefix="generateKey(loan, budget)"
                :paymentSummary="paymentSummary[budget.id]"
                :title="
                  builders.buildAmortizationTableTitle(
                    loan,
                    budget,
                    loanPrimitives.getLoanIndex(loan.id)
                  )
                "
              />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template #actions>
      <base-button :class="['createButton']" @click="emitExit"
        >Close</base-button
      >
    </template>
  </base-modal>
</template>

<style scoped>
  input::after {}
</style>


Can you create a reproducible link so the it would be easier for anyone to help here, as as per code shared it looks good.

Could you spot the difference by checking the styling difference in the DOM?

@YashMaheshwari I have it hosted on gh-pages: https://kylep342.github.io/debtonate/

@KPekosh Can you add steps to navigate to the section where tabs are displayed?

@YashMaheshwari
Create a few loans, and create a few budgets. On a loan or budget card, press "view". You will see the list of tabs above (Labeled 'Budget 1', 'Budget 2', ..., 'Budget N', 'Minimum Budget'). Click one of the tabs to open the table and observe the behavior above.
